# Sharepoint site showing up even though user has no permissions to it

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I have a WSS installation with quite a few sites and subsites. I recently enabled forms-based authentication and allowed the forms-users access to *one* sub-site of a single site. That works fine - the only problem is that a separate site shows up in the top bar and is the only one that shows up. I checked all the permissions and I can't find any reference to this user in the site nor it's subsites (shouldn't exist because I *just* created the user). Trying to access these sites as this user gives me access denied. The only thing I can think of is that some portion of the subsites (document libraries etc) or a specific file has some strange permissions for everyone... I just don't know how to programmatically check the effective permissions on all documents; doing it by hand is just not feasible. Any ideas?

User was granted access to Subsite 1 of Site A. In the top bar, they *only* see Site B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't sound like a permissions problem (if they are being given access denied when they try to access Site B, then all is working as it should be).  It sounds like you need to modify the navigation (information on how to do that here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA101191001033.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that appears to be the issue.. however, I can't see to figure out how to actually fix it :-). It seems whoever set it up did not put the site in the top bar and added it as an afterthought.  Now, the top bar entry is editable. The rest of the sites are not (if you try to edit any of the sites that are correct, it shows up as grayed out and the path is /siteA/default.aspx). I can't find anything in the GUI to restore the original link... I might have to go and manipulate the database unless you have any ideas :(

Comment: No... don't go manipulating the database.  No good will come of that ;)

I'm a little confused about what you are seeing.  It should be simple to add another tab to the top bar (known as Global Navigation) to point wherever you'd like.  I don't have a WSS server handy to look for the exact options, but when you are in the Navigation Settings referenced in the link I provided, play with the "Display the same navigation items as the parent site" option, or manually add an entry under Global Navigation in the "Navigation Editing and Sorting" section

Comment: It was not possible to fix this via the GUI: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/e745573d-4536-490a-8a64-48caf3b4e8b5  

I ended up maniuplating the database (NavNodes table) and it worked perfectly! Everything still works and the link is gone from the form-based auth site :-)  Thanks for the pointer to the TopBar info!

Comment: And just to clarify: I thoroughly tested my database manipulation on a sandbox system before I even touched the production box! ;)

Comment: I'm the PM responsible for permissions in SharePoint. I can't stress enough how bad an idea modifying the database is. Doing so puts you in an unsupported state.

Comment: As per my link above, I didn't have any supported way to do this and re-creating an entire site's worth of data is a bit much to ask. I looked at a before and after of the db after deleting the proper TopBar link and re-adding it, and then reversed those changes. (Changed the DocID to the ID from the AllDocs table [SELECT ID FROM AllDocs WHERE DirName = 'SITEURL' AND LeafName = 'Default.aspx'] , changed the Url to NULL, and changed the element type to 0)